# Auth0: Validating id_token/JWT on UI (javascript) level

Tags: authentication, react-redux, jwt, access-token, auth0

**Update March 2019**

I just went over this question again; the Auth0's github code has been updated in December 2018. They are now storing 'access_token','id_token' and 'expire_at' into the object/session, instead of localstorage and using now an 'isLoggedIn' flag to mark if authenticated or not. Check the [pull request](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/pull/99) and these 2 lines in the specific commit: [line1](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/pull/99/commits/d1f7227dc1b3699ead0d6b1161db636f4dc3d1c5#diff-e183ac7c0c4d46d1cc9eca56834aab1aR55) and [line2](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/pull/99/commits/d1f7227dc1b3699ead0d6b1161db636f4dc3d1c5#diff-e183ac7c0c4d46d1cc9eca56834aab1aL85).

If you do not need to re-validate 'id_token' - like I was doing in the original question - that might be an alternative. Otherwise check original question.

---

**Original Question**

We are using [auth0](https://auth0.com) for one of our clients. One stack that we are using it for is:

- React/Redux UI
- NodeJS backend

So we are using a cross origin authentication using implicit grant for that, using JWT with an RS256 algorithm. We also refresh tokens in background using silent authentication.

I was able to validate 'access_token' on the API (nodejs) side using [node-jwks-rsa for express](https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa/tree/master/examples/express-demo)

On the UI level, after going through the source code of the **auth0-js** library I noticed that the "parseHash" method used in their provided react samples, actually validates tokens before we store them in localstorage, ie on successful authentication. Mainly [this line in the source code.](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js/blob/5ffc5325db35794ca2038bc60220f0cfce8eccf3/src/web-auth/index.js#L125)

Then I used their sample code that allows us to check if a user is authenticated, method [isAuthenticated().](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/blob/master/01-Login/src/Auth/Auth.js#L91)

**Problem with the [isAuthenticated()](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/blob/master/01-Login/src/Auth/Auth.js#L91) method**

From a security perspective, if later on (post authentication) a user of the application decided to manually modify the 'expire_at' label in the storage, they could get away as indeed authenticated. While of course there is additional security checking in our app, I wanted to update this function to validate 'id_token'. So far, I couldn't find any example in auth0's online docs for how to do that.

After digging in their source code I found a method [validateToken](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js/blob/5ffc5325db35794ca2038bc60220f0cfce8eccf3/src/web-auth/index.js#L195) that is being used. So I decided to leverage it in one of our functions:

```
import IdTokenVerifier from 'idtoken-verifier'
.... Some code in here ....

reValidateToken() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Both of these are stored in localstorage on successful authentication, using the parseHash method
    let id_token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    let transactionNonce = localStorage.getItem('app_nonce');

    this.webAuth.validateToken(id_token, transactionNonce, function(
        validationError,
        payload
    ) {
        if (!validationError) {
            resolve('no validation errors for id_token');
        }

        if (validationError.error !== 'invalid_token') {
            reject(validationError.error);
        }

        // if it's an invalid_token error, decode the token
        var decodedToken = new IdTokenVerifier().decode(id_token);

        // if the alg is not HS256, return the raw error
        if (decodedToken.header.alg !== 'HS256') {
            reject(validationError);
        }
    });
  });
}`
```

Now, for it to succeed; we store the **nonce** in localstorage after successful authentication, does this approach create back doors for potential security holes? if it does; what is best practice to validate RS256 JWT id_token(s) on a UI level?